# How to get JavaScript to recognize 2 links and open them both in separate tabs on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

JavaScript is combining two seperate links and opening them in the same `tab`, which is a                dead link.

Ex. If I tweet'Laser Blue' is now available http://swoo.sh/14F9swF   pic.twitter.com/xb6Hm1UnX9, it will open a new `tab`, and go to http://swoo.sh/14F9swFpic.twitter.com/xb6Hm1UnX9, which is a dead link.

I'd like it to recognize both links, and open them in 2 seperate tabs.

Ex. Tab 1. ttp://swoo.sh/14F9swF Tab 2. pic.twitter.com/xb6Hm1UnX9.

NOTE: I Do NOT have the link before hand.Javascript has to detect the link.

This is the script. It is in `backround.js`.

Thankyou.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

function test() {
req.open(
    "GET",
    "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nikestore&count=1550&exclude_replies=true&trim_user=true",
    true);
req.onload = showTweets;
req.send(null);

setTimeout(test, 3000);
}

function showTweets() {
var data = req.responseText;

var tweets = $.parseJSON(data);

$.each(tweets, function (data) {

    var id = this.id;
    var txt = this.text;

if(!txt) {
    return false;
    }

    var link = txt.substring(txt.indexOf("http://"));
    var lastTweet = localStorage["lastTweet"];

    //var txt = txt.replace("\u2018", "").replace("\u2019", "");
    var z = localStorage["keyword"];

    if (txt.toLowerCase().indexOf("now available") >= 0 && id != lastTweet) {
        if (localStorage["keyword"] && txt.indexOf(localStorage["keyword"]) >= 0) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url:link});

            localStorage["lastTweet"] = id;

            return false;
        }
    }
    else if (id == lastTweet)
    {
        return false;
    }
});
}

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.command == "startCheck") {
      setTimeout(test, 3000);
  }
  else if (request.command == "stopCheck") {
      clearTimeout(test);
  }
 });
```

Comment: I believe the main focus should be on chrome.tabs.create ({url:link});

Comment: Have yout ried using `chrome.tabs.create` twice (for each link)?

Comment: Yes. I did chrome.tabs.create ([url:link]) twice and and it just searched the dead link in two tabs. Since I don't know the links before hand I can't enter a specific link.

Comment: Are the links written in any consistent wya?

Comment: Yes. The pic.twitter link is always last. Come to think of it, I don't even need the second link to open. I just need javascript to ignore it and open the first one in a new tab. But I wouldn't mind if it opened both in separate tabs.